# Summation of two asymptotic functions

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Suppose we have $f_1(x) = O(g_1(x))$ and $f_2(x) = O(g_2(x))$, then what is $(f_1(x) + f_2(x))$?

What I know is asymptomatic notations are closed under summation. So, $(f_1(x) + f_2(x)) = O((g_1(x) + g_2(x))$

But now my question is first am I right?

If so, then why the answer cannot be $O(\max(g_1(x),g_2(x)))$ ? For example, $O(n + \log(n)) = O(\max(n, \log(n))) = O(n)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both of your thoughts are correct, assuming  $g_1(x),g_2(x)$ are positive (as they should be).

Comment: `asymptomatic notations are closed under summation` Not as written, but rather $f_1+f_2=\mathcal{O}(|g_1|+|g_2|)$.

Comment: @dxiv, ok, if $g_1(x)$ or $g_2(x)$ are negative, then $max(g_1(x), g_2(x))$ will hold, right?

Comment: @Apy No, consider for example $f_1(x)=g_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=x,g_2(x)= -x$. Then $f_1+f_2$ is *not* $\mathcal{O}(\max(g_1,g_2))=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: @dxiv If $g_2(x) = -x$ how can it upper bound $f_1(x) = x$ ?

Comment: @Apy Big-$\mathcal{O}$ does *not* mean "*upper-bound*". Note that the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) involves some absolute values.

Comment: @dxiv, yeah but Big O can be compared with ">=". So, how can you claim -x >= x ?

Comment: @Apy Please don't misquote me, I never claimed that $-x \ge x$ (when $x \to \infty\,$, for context). But $x = \mathcal{O}(-x)$ if you re-read the definition I pointed to more carefully.

Comment: @dxiv, I'm just learning. Hope it's not bothering you. Can you please explain what are you trying to say with more examples?

Comment: @Apy The definition of $\mathcal{O}$ only ever refers to the absolute values of the functions involved. The $\max$ alternative you propose compares *signed* values, not absolute ones, so it can't possibly work. If your real question is why $\mathcal{O}(n+\ln(n))=\mathcal{O}(n)$ (which is indeed the case, since $\ln(n) / n \to 0$) then you should rather ask that directly.

Comment: @dxiv, ok! I saw it. The $|g(x)|$. But what I learnt that $g(x)$ "upper bounds" $f(x)$, and those graphs that professors drew were completely wrong. I'm just super-confused!

Comment: @Apy There was most likely some assumption of $f, g \ge 0$ hidden somewhere.

Comment: @dxiv Yes! You're a genius! Thanks! I got it :D Heyyyy! Can you make the answer, so that I can mark this question as accepted?

Comment: @Apy Glad you worked it out. I just happened to have had some of the same questions sorted out already ;-)